# Oracle database 19C moving back and forth with time without resetlogs

Tags: oracle-19c

my client have a oracle database 19C on windows server 2016
for a business reason he need to be able to move back in time to specific date/time and modify some data and then move forth to the current date with the same database using archive logs and without opening database with resetlogs

i did check flashback and point in time recovery and it always ends up opening the database with resetlogs

is it doable ? if there is some other way please share

Comment: This seems a little too localized, and could use more details to help us understand you better. The truth of the matter is that this seems like a poor workaround hack in need of a better actual fix.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is an "X-Y Question" (Asking for *one* thing, "X", whilst actually wanting to achieve something *else*, "Y").
Mucking about, spinning the database back and forth "through time" is inherently dangerous *and* intrusive *and*, most likely, *will not* achieve what the client wants.
Being able to Flash-back and Flash-forward the database relies in *all* the changes involved being in the Database FlashBack Logs.  As soon as you make changes to the "earlier" database, you cannot Flash it "forward" again without losing the changes you made "back then".

It's like every Time-Travel movie you've ever seen, where the villain goes back in time and changes something in the Past, thereby re-writing the Present.  The only way to "rescue" the situation is to undo whenever they did (and that's basically what Flash-"forward" does).

Restate the [actual] problem.
What does the client *actually* want to achieve?

Databases accumulate data over time so if the client wants to change some "earlier" data, then they need to identify *which* data, *what* they want to do to it and then come and talk to *you* about the best way to do so (which *shouldn't* involve Database Recovery techniques, just regular insert/update/delete-type stuff).

And if, they've already tried that and something "in" the database *actively* prevented them from doing so, then there's probably a very Good Reason that it did so ...

Comment: sadly the client refuses to tell claiming it's confidential details related to their " banking business " the only clause he mentioned that he need to go back in time without using resetlogs so he would be able to re-use the archive logs he has to move forward in time or even move back again

Comment: Distance yourself from this situation (and, potentially, this client) immediately!  
Raise the matter with your manager/supervisor.  
For a person working in a "banking business" to want to go back and "cook the books" in such a circuitous and, frankly, dubious manner is highly questionable and, potentially, bordering on the illegal.  
There should be nothing to stop this person from making the changes that they wish to make through more "mainstream" channels and if there /is/ something stopping them, then they shouldn't be doing it!

Comment: I agree with @PhillW. Not only is this *not* doable, it is *highly* suspect behavior, especially since they refuse to clarify the requirement. It should be reported not only with your management, but possibly to authorities. At a minimum it sounds like your company lawyer(s) should be involved.

Comment: I did as you advised and escalated it to my managers . thanks alot